# Get max date from each specific user ID without repeating IDs using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have the following XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
    <Data>
        <Record>
            <User>1</User>
            <LastModified>1/1/2023</LastModified>
            <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <User>1</User>
            <LastModified>1/11/2023</LastModified>
            <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <User>2</User>
            <LastModified>1/1/2024</LastModified>
            <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <User>2</User>
            <LastModified>1/12/2023</LastModified>
            <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <User>3</User>
            <LastModified>5/7/2023</LastModified>
            <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <User>3</User>
            <LastModified>9/8/2023</LastModified>
            <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <User>4</User>
            <LastModified>24/1/2023</LastModified>
            <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <User>4</User>
            <LastModified>28/9/2023</LastModified>
            <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <User>5</User>
            <LastModified>15/3/2023</LastModified>
            <UniversityDegree>University of Texas Bachelors</UniversityDegree>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <User>5</User>
            <LastModified>10/3/2023</LastModified>
            <UniversityDegree>University of Missouri Masters</UniversityDegree>
        </Record>
    </Data>
</root>
```

And I need to extract the max date of each user, so for example out of use 5 the max date from 15/3/2023 and 10/3/2023 is 15/3/2023 and show it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LastModified>15/3/2023</LastModified>
<User>5</User>
```

I've done the following,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="//root">
      <xsl:for-each select="//Record">
         <xsl:sort select="number(substring(LastModified, 7, 4))" order="descending"/>
         <xsl:sort select="number(substring(LastModified, 3, 2))" order="descending"/>
         <xsl:sort select="number(substring(LastModified, 1, 2))" order="descending"/>
         
         
         <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:copy-of select="LastModified"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="User"/>
            <Source>SF</Source>
         </xsl:if>

      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which returns,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LastModified>1/1/2024</LastModified>
<User>2</User>
<Source>SF</Source>
```

But it only returns the first sorted record due to the position 1 if. I would need to get the max date of each of the users without having duplicates. If I remove the IF condition, I get everything sorted but Users are repeated,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LastModified>1/1/2024</LastModified>
<User>2</User>
<Source>SF</Source>
<LastModified>1/12/2023</LastModified>
<User>2</User>
<Source>SF</Source>
<LastModified>1/11/2023</LastModified>
<User>1</User>
<Source>SF</Source>
<LastModified>28/9/2023</LastModified>
<User>4</User>
<Source>SF</Source>
<LastModified>24/1/2023</LastModified>
<User>4</User>
<Source>SF</Source>
<LastModified>15/3/2023</LastModified>
<User>5</User>
<Source>SF</Source>
<LastModified>10/3/2023</LastModified>
<User>5</User>
<Source>SF</Source>
<LastModified>1/1/2023</LastModified>
<User>1</User>
<Source>SF</Source>
<LastModified>5/7/2023</LastModified>
<User>3</User>
<Source>SF</Source>
<LastModified>9/8/2023</LastModified>
<User>3</User>
<Source>SF</Source>
```

Comment: Do note that your sorting method is wrong: you cannot use absolute positions with dates that do not have leading zeros for days and months.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Noted, thanks; comment deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try perhaps something like:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <result>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Data/Record" group-by="User">
            <user>
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:sort select="tokenize(LastModified, '/')[3]" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                    <xsl:sort select="tokenize(LastModified, '/')[2]" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                    <xsl:sort select="tokenize(LastModified, '/')[1]" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="LastModified, User"/>
                        <Source>SF</Source>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </user>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Caveat: not tested very thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you, looks like it work, I will make the payload bigger and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat different approach that's not necessarily better, but it takes advantage of more XSLT 2.0 features:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:mf="http://www.example.com/mf"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <result>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Data/Record" group-by="User">
            <user>
                <LastModified>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-date(max(current-group()/LastModified/mf:reformat-date(.)), '[D]/[M]/[Y]')"/>
                </LastModified>
                <xsl:copy-of select="User"/>
                <Source>SF</Source>
            </user>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="mf:reformat-date" as="xs:date">
    <!-- expected input format: d/m/y -->
    <xsl:param name="date"/> 
    <xsl:variable name="components" select="for $t in tokenize($date, '/') return xs:integer($t)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($components[3], '0000'), format-number($components[2], '00'), format-number($components[1], '00')" separator="-"/>
</xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```